# jQuery UI - Plugin for inputting a number as hex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, spinner

On a recent project, I need have a hex mask (0x0 - 0xFF) as one of the input fields on an HTML form. I know I could just use a regular input to get the hex value, and then I can validate it along with the other form submission validation.

However, for some of the other decimal fields I am using [ui.spinner.js (github)](http://github.com/btburnett3/jquery.ui.spinner/blob/master/ui.spinner.js) to allow the user to hit the up/down buttons to toggle the value of the number. It would be nice to have a similar control for inputting hex values. Or at least, a control that is a bit "richer" than a simple input element.

Does anyone know if such a plugin exists?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I neglected to mention the spinner control that I am using. My apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving this by writing custom `format` and `parse` handlers, as well as overriding the keypress event to enalble the user to type in hex digits:

```
        // Functions for dealing with hex values in spinners
        var parseHex = function(val) {
                    var options = this;

                    if (options.group == '.')
                        val = val.replace('.', '');
                    if (options.point != '.')
                        val = val.replace(options.point, '.');
                    return parseFloat(parseInt(val, 16));
                },
            formatHex = function(num, places) {
                    var options = this,
                    regex = /(\d+)(\d{3})/,
                    result = ((isNaN(num) ? 0 : Math.abs(num)).toFixed(places)) + '';

                    for (result = result.replace('.', options.point); regex.test(result) && options.group; result=result.replace(regex, '$1'+options.group+'$2')) {};
                    return (num < 0 ? '-' : '') + options.prefix + parseInt(result).toString(16) + options.suffix;
                },
             keypressHex = function(e) {
                var ch = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode || e.keyCode)
                if (((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9')) || ((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'f')))
                    return true;
                return false;
             };

        jQuery('#myinput')
            .spinner({
                min: 0,
                max: 255,
                prefix: '0x',
                format: formatHex,
                parse: parseHex});
        jQuery('#myinput').unbind('keypress.uispinner'); // Explicitly remove the controls keypress validation
        jQuery('#myinput').bind('keypress.uispinner', keypressHex);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen one.  It shouldn't be too hard to make the spinner do hex though - either make a select box with 0x00 - 0xFF as values, or do a regular spinner from 0 - 256 & convert to hex in the spin() event.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you could probably still use the jQuery UI Spinner to do this.  I have not tested anything but I would look at two possible options.

1. Create a UL's through javascript, with its LI's the list of 0x00 - 0xff.  Then, use `$("#your_ul_id").spinner();`
2. Try using the spin event handler to change the output by converting to appropriate hex.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently had the same requirement, and I wrote the following plugin to solve it: https://github.com/bubasti/jQuery-Hex-Input

It's using the jQuery widget factory and is making use of the jQuery 1.9 Spinner widget.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! The OP's solution here completely failed (it seems that options like 'format' and 'parse' and 'prefix' do not exist any more) and this looks very promising. Only, would it be possible to make the expand/collapse entry method optional (I only want to use the spinner)? And how about on-keypress validation within the spinner, how might I approach that?

Comment: On further investigation, I've found that this doesn't really suit my needs. The main piece I was missing to make the "convert to hex in the spin() event" logic work is that the Spinner has pre-parsed the display value internally, which is fine if you have a `0x` prefix but breaks otherwise (since `+` is used to coerce the value). I am now rolling my own solution based on the investigation at http://benknowscode.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/exploring-the-new-jquery-ui-spinner-beyond-the-basics/ , and hope to eventually have something nicely reusable and general.