# Can the HTML5 input type number be used with hexadecimal numbers?

Tags: html, forms, input, hex

Is there any way to make the HTML5 form input type "number" work with numbers in bases other than 10? For example, I would like to use the features of the number input type (up/down arrows, browser validation) with hexadecimal numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The W3C specs says that the number input value can only be a floating point number http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.number.html#input.number.attrs.value , so the value is defined in here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/datatypes.html#common.data.float 
If you'd like to have similar functionalities you can consider to use the [jQuery UI spinner](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/) and check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230619/jquery-ui-plugin-for-inputting-a-number-as-hex) for thoughts.

Comment: Thanks for the links to the spec. I was hoping W3C had thought of those of us who use all 16 of their fingers for counting...